# Subset specific rows and the following ones in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to know whether there is some simple way of subsetting a dataframe for specific rows and also including the 3 following rows.

I have a dataframe [df]

```
id   device   date                pressure    warning
1    B3       2020-04-15 08:00    112         0
2    B3       2020-04-15 09:00    67          1
3    B3       2020-04-15 10:00    13          0
4    B3       2020-04-15 11:00    0           0
5    B3       2020-04-15 12:00    12          0
6    B3       2020-04-15 13:00    28          0
7    B3       2020-04-16 09:00    120         0
8    B3       2020-04-16 10:00    80          1
9    B3       2020-04-16 11:00    0           0
10   B3       2020-04-16 12:00    19          0
11   B3       2020-04-16 13:00    30          0
```

I would like to subset the dataframe to the rows which have a warning == 1 and the following 3 rows.

The preferred result would be like this:

```
id   device   date                pressure    warning
2    B3       2020-04-15 09:00    67          1
3    B3       2020-04-15 10:00    13          0
4    B3       2020-04-15 11:00    0           0
5    B3       2020-04-15 12:00    12          0
8    B3       2020-04-16 10:00    80          1
9    B3       2020-04-16 11:00    0           0
10   B3       2020-04-16 12:00    19          0
11   B3       2020-04-16 13:00    30          0
```

s there any way of doing this in R?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df <- df[unique(pmin(c(sapply(which(df$warning == 1), function(x) x:(x+3))), nrow(df))),]
```

To get ids for the groups:

```
df$id <- cumsum(df$warning) + 1
```

Comment: would it also be possible to assigne each of these groups of 4 rows a simple group id? By that I mean a creation of a new column which would assign each group of 4 a different number.

Comment: @dloudtrain - before or after subsetting?

Comment: @H 1 I think after subsetting so that each group starting by warning ==1 would have a unique ID.

Comment: @dloudtrain - see edit - made a minor amendment to the original so that the subset indices can't exceed the rows of the data frame.

Comment: could you please include the first version of your idea before amendments so that it can exceed the rows of the dataframe? The last version ends up in error: Error in x:(x + 3) : NA/NaN argument. Coul you please advise on this?

Comment: @dloudtrain - sorry about that, edit was sloppy and broke it.  Fixed now.